# C++ vector of threads randomly crash when join

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm using a vector of threads to do the heavy lifting, after which I call join on them. Sometimes, everything works fine, and they get joined up as intended. However, on some occasions, which to me can't help but look random, they crash saying vector iterators are from a different container.

This is the function where I'm doing multithreading.

```cpp
int FindPath(const int nStartX, const int nStartY,
    const int nTargetX, const int nTargetY,
    const unsigned char* pMap, const int nMapWidth, const int nMapHeight,
    int* pOutBuffer, const int nOutBufferSize)
{
    vector<Node> nodes(nMapWidth * nMapHeight);
    priority_queue<Node*, vector<Node*>, Compare> queue;
    vector<thread> threads;

    getNodes(nodes, nStartX, nStartY, nTargetX, nTargetY, pMap, nMapWidth, nMapHeight);

    queue.push(&nodes[getCoord(nMapWidth, nStartX, nStartY)]);

    for (auto i = 0; i < thread::hardware_concurrency(); ++i)
    {
        threads.push_back(thread(doWork, ref(queue)));
    }
    for (auto& worker : threads)
    {
        worker.join();
    }

    if (nodes[getCoord(nMapWidth, nTargetX, nTargetY)].prev)
    {
        vector<int> path;

        getPath(path, nodes[getCoord(nMapWidth, nTargetX, nTargetY)]);

        for (auto i = 0; i < nOutBufferSize; ++i)
        {
            if (i >= path.size())
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                pOutBuffer[i] = path[i];
            }
        }

        return path.size();
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

This part, in particular, is where the crash randomly occurs.

```cpp
for (auto& worker : threads)
{
    worker.join();
}
```

```cpp
void doWork(priority_queue<Node*, vector<Node*>, Compare>& queue)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (!queue.size())
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> ml(mtx);
            cv.wait_until(ml, chrono::system_clock::now() + 10ms);

            if (!queue.size())
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Node* node = queue.top();
            queue.pop();

            for (auto neighb : node->neighb)
            {
                if (node->distPrev + neighb.second < neighb.first->distPrev)
                {
                    neighb.first->distPrev = node->distPrev + neighb.second;
                    neighb.first->prev = node;

                    queue.push(neighb.first);

                    cv.notify_one();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In case it helps, I'm using the VSS 2019 community version.

Comment: Have you checked what each thread is doing when the crash occurs? It might be caused by `doWork()`.

Comment: why don't you use `joinable`?

Comment: Oh, I think that's what's been causing the problem. How do I prevent threads from being joined immediately after they're created?

Comment: Another idea to investigate the issue is that you are using a priority queue concurrently, which may be a problem. Please provide more information what `doWork` does; in particular information about writes to the priority queue.

Comment: @재형김 That should normally not be a problem: `join` will block until the thread finishes if it hasn't done so yet. The problem will likely be somewhere in `doWork`. For example, is the access to `queue` properly synchronised?

Comment: I'll upload that part of the code as well, thanks!

Comment: You have plenty of concurrent access to the queue that you need to avoid.

Comment: I'm very new to multithreading, so if you don't mind, could you perhaps point out the basics?

Comment: At the very least you're calling `queue.pop()` (and other `queue` members) in `doWork` without having obtained the mutex `mlx`.  That's undefined behaviour.

Comment: @oblivion -- all the threads here are joinable; there's no need to check for it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to synchronise around all your reading and writing to the queue.

Something like this (untested, for obvious reasons):

```
void doWork(priority_queue<Node*, vector<Node*>, Compare>& queue)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Node* node = nullptr;
        {
            // Wait for an item to appear, or 10 ms to pass.
            unique_lock<mutex> ml(mtx);
            if (queue.empty())
            {
                // If the queue is still empty after 10ms, break out.
                if (!cv.wait_for(ml, 10ms, [&queue]() { return !queue.empty(); }))
                    break;
            }
            // The queue can't be empty here.
            node = queue.top();
            queue.pop();
        }

        // Add neighbours.
        for (auto neighb : node->neighb)
        {
            if (node->distPrev + neighb.second < neighb.first->distPrev)
            {
                neighb.first->distPrev = node->distPrev + neighb.second;
                neighb.first->prev = node;
                // Lock while adding to the queue.
                unique_lock<mutex> ml(mtx);
                queue.push(neighb.first);
                cv.notify_one();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that "the queue is empty after waiting ten milliseconds" is not a very robust way of determining that the work is done.

Or split in two functions:

```
Node* fetch_next(priority_queue<Node*, vector<Node*>, Compare>& queue)
{
    unique_lock<mutex> ml(mtx);
    if (queue.empty())
    {
        if (!cv.wait_for(ml, 10ms, [&queue]() { return !queue.empty(); }))
            return nullptr;
    }
    Node* node = queue.top();
    queue.pop();
    return node;
}

void doWork(priority_queue<Node*, vector<Node*>, Compare>& queue)
{
    while (Node* node = fetch_next(queue))
    {
        for (auto neighb : node->neighb)
        {
            if (node->distPrev + neighb.second < neighb.first->distPrev)
            {
                neighb.first->distPrev = node->distPrev + neighb.second;
                neighb.first->prev = node;
                unique_lock<mutex> ml(mtx);
                queue.push(neighb.first);
                cv.notify_one();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is: the following code in dowork() gets executed asynchronously by multiple threads and hence the issue:

```
if (!queue.size())
```

and in else block, the queue is accessed as follows, again asynchronously by multiple threads:

```
Node* node = queue.top();
queue.pop();
```

It may be a better idea to protect above code snippets under the mutex as well?